# Is there a way to speed up Google Optimize redirect or do it server-side?

Tags: redirect, google-website-optimizer

If you setup the redirect test in Google Optimize, you get a huge increase in load time for both original and variant. I was looking for a solution and found this guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-server-side. Unfortunately, as our off-site developer said, it's going to take a lot of hours to implement each experiment. Can anybody help? Thanks